# Certificate Wizard Broken on NetBeans with CodeNameOne update?

Tags: codenameone

I am checking out CodeNameOne...neat stuff!

I had a simple app working before the latest 3.5 update using NetBeans. I had used the ios certificate wizard and successfully deployed to my iphone.

I upgraded the plugin this morning to the latest 3.5 version and now get the following error below when clicking on the "Generate" button. Any ideas on how to fix?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codename1.services.certwizard.SEWrapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.codename1.services.certwizard.CN1CertificateWizard.init(CN1CertificateWizard.java:137)
[catch] at com.codename1.services.certwizard.CN1CertificateWizard.show(CN1CertificateWizard.java:166)
    at com.codename1.forms.IOSPropertiesPanel$11.run(IOSPropertiesPanel.java:779)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Try the new Codename One settings UI under Codename One -> Codename One Settings.

Comment: that worked. Thanks!